# Send a email in Grails 3 with an image in it

Tags: image, grails, asset-pipeline, grails-3.0

I am trying to send an image within an email when in Development for a Grails 3 project.   The email is sent through AWS email service.   I have tried the img tag with absolute equal to true but have been unable to succeed in seeing the image in the email?  Using asset-pipeline so it might be something related to that.

How do you achieve seeing the image in a email?

Comment: can you show your grails aws conf. here for sending the mail so that  we can help you out !

Answer (score 0):

I used asynchronous send mail grails plugin for mail with image code part as follows:

```
File f = new File("IMG.jpg")
asynchronousMailService.sendMail {
                from "senderMailID"
                to  "recipientsMailID"
                bcc "BCCMailID"
                subject "subject"
                html "html code"
                inline 'YourImageName', 'image/jpg', f
            }
```

Then your HTML codes contains

```
<img src="cid:YourImageName" style="height: 60px">
```

I hope this helps you!

Comment: Thanks but I am using the AWS email service so this won't work and I can't switch to the other plugin.  Appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you to use this grails plugin sending image or text etc. attachment through AWS.

http://grails-aws.github.io/grails-aws/1.7.5.0/guide/3%20Amazon%20Simple%20Email%20Service%20(AWS%20SES).html

And if your done with AWS mail configuration then you can use mail service like this:

```
Mail {
    to "email@gmailcom"
    subject "testing emails with one attachment"
     body "..."
    attach "/users/website/images/file1.jpg"
}
```

Hope this will help you!

Comment: Ahh, thanks for the suggestion but I want the picture in the email content like a logo not as an attachment.  I ended up just using a external s3 link for now.